# Spring boot hibernate bidirectional mapping many to one can not established relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity table one category and other is subject

My category entity

```
@Entity
public class Category extends AuditableEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String name;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "description_id")
private CategoryDescription description;

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Subject> subjects;

//getter and setter
}
```

And my Subject entity

```
@Entity
public class Subject extends AuditableEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String name;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "description_id")
private SubjectDescription description;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Category category;

//Getter and Setter
}
```

Category Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CategoryRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
}
```

Subject Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, 
Integer> {
}
```

Category Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category/api/")
public class CategoryResource {

private final CategoryService categoryService;
private final SubjectService subjectService;
private final TopicService topicService;

public CategoryResource(CategoryService categoryService, 
SubjectService subjectService, TopicService topicService) {
    this.categoryService = categoryService;
    this.subjectService = subjectService;
    this.topicService = topicService;
}

@PostMapping("save")
public void saveCategory(@RequestBody Category category) {

    categoryService.save(category);

}
```

I am using postman to save data. Problem is that after saving data to the category and subject table my subject table column category_id is  null i can not established a relationship between them my sql structure and data is after saving data it shows like

Category table

[image]

Subject Table

[image]

category_id is NULL how to set category id i am trying many ways but couldn't find a solution.Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's great that you are learning spring boot!

To answer your question since the answer is pretty simple, your code is missing category in subject.

```
subject.setCategory(category);
```

Now this might cause you an exception, so make sure you save category before you persist subject.

Cheers!

Comment: not working same as before @thechaoticpanda

Comment: are you sure that your category is saved before you do so?

Comment: Ahh, this is why your code might not be working, as I said in the answer, 
please save category before setting it in subject and saving

Comment: @thechaoticpanda He doesn't need to save additionally a category or subject  because of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. Hibernate smart enough to save category firstly and get an id of it.

Comment: @Partho It should work. Extend your question with the changes provided in this answer.

Comment: @v.ladynev , yes you are right, I have noticed that, but was not quite sure, thus I told him, it might throw an exception, also, I always prefer to detach them from each other, for better control when deleting tuples.